# JAX-RS: How to navigate to Response method to get all resources?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I want to implement method to get All Orders when I send request on: **localhost:8080/ProjectName/MyApplication/orders**

Now when I access that location in my web browser I got:

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

```
@Path("orders")  
public class MehanicarServis {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public Response getOrders() {
     try {
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(DB.LOCATION, DB.USER, DB.PASS);
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM orders";
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(query);
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        while (r.next()) {
            orders.add(new Order(r.getInt("id"), r.getString("name")));
        }
        GenericEntity<List<Order>> gOrders = new GenericEntity<List<Order>>(orders) {};
        return Response.status(200).entity(gOrders).build();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MehanicarServis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }   
    }
```

Method is right, there's no problems, but **I have problem to invoke this Response method** over URL in browser? What should i change in URL example to invoke it?

P.S. I've implemented MyApplication class which extends Application, so in my opinion mistake is somewhere between annotations of *getOrders()*?

Comment: can you check your port (if your server is running on 8080 or not) and the base url part (ProjectName/MyApplication) in your web.xml (or equivalent).

Comment: In the sqlExecption you should return a response with status code 500

Comment: did you try overriding 
```Application#getClasses()
```
and add your specific Ressource there?